# DataTypeNotSupportedError: Data type "Object" in "Photo.user" is not supported by "postgres" database

Tags: typeorm, one-to-many

I'm trying to run the exact same code written in [ManyToOne and OneToMany relations](https://typeorm.io/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations) in the typeORM docs. On compilation, this is the error I get: `DataTypeNotSupportedError: Data type "Object" in "Photo.user" is not supported by "postgres" database`

According to the docs, it should create a user table and a photo table where there will be a foreign key to the user table, called userId.

So why is this happening? How can I fix this?